# Using custom property types in Azure Tables with ASP.NET 5 DNX Core

Tags: serialization, asp.net-core, azure-table-storage, dnx, custom-type

Azure Table Storage [does not support](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd179338.aspx) many property types (List<>, TimeSpan, etc).

There are solutions like Lucifure Stash and Lokad.Cloud, but they are not compiling for DNX Core 5.0.

Is there a way to add support for custom property types in Azure Tables with DNX Core?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One solution is to use reflection to iterate through all the “custom” properties of the entity and serialize them to JSON strings.

We can override TableEntity’s `ReadEntity` and `WriteEntity` methods to hook de-/serialization:

```cs
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

public abstract class CustomEntity : TableEntity
{
    public override IDictionary<string, EntityProperty> WriteEntity (OperationContext operationContext)
    {
        var properties = base.WriteEntity(operationContext);

        // Iterating through the properties of the entity
        foreach (var property in GetType().GetProperties().Where(property =>
                // Excluding props explicitly marked to ignore serialization
                !property.GetCustomAttributes<IgnorePropertyAttribute>(true).Any() &&
                // Excluding already serialized props
                !properties.ContainsKey(property.Name) &&
                // Excluding internal TableEntity props
                typeof(TableEntity).GetProperties().All(p => p.Name != property.Name)))
        {
            var value = property.GetValue(this);
            if (value != null)
                // Serializing property to JSON
                properties.Add(property.Name, new EntityProperty(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value)));
        }

        return properties;
    }

    public override void ReadEntity (IDictionary<string, EntityProperty> properties, OperationContext operationContext)
    {
        base.ReadEntity(properties, operationContext);

        // Iterating through the properties of the entity
        foreach (var property in GetType().GetProperties().Where(property =>
                // Excluding props explicitly marked to ignore serialization
                !property.GetCustomAttributes<IgnorePropertyAttribute>(true).Any() &&
                // Excluding props which were not originally serialized
                properties.ContainsKey(property.Name) &&
                // Excluding props with target type of string (they are natively supported)
                property.PropertyType != typeof(string) &&
                // Excluding non-string table fields (this will filter-out 
                // all the remaining natively supported props like byte, DateTime, etc)
                properties[property.Name].PropertyType == EdmType.String))
        {
            // Checking if property contains a valid JSON
            var jToken = TryParseJson(properties[property.Name].StringValue);
            if (jToken != null)
            {
                // Constructing method for deserialization 
                var toObjectMethod = jToken.GetType().GetMethod("ToObject", new[] { typeof(Type) });
                // Invoking the method with the target property type; eg, jToken.ToObject(CustomType)
                var value = toObjectMethod.Invoke(jToken, new object[] { property.PropertyType });

                property.SetValue(this, value);
            }
        }
    }

    private static JToken TryParseJson (string s)
    {
        try { return JToken.Parse(s); }
        catch (JsonReaderException) { return null; }
    }
}
```

Now, if we inherit our table entities from the `CustomEntity` class, we can freely use properties with any types supported by Json.NET.

Comment: We've noticed a problem with this code - the call to property.GetType() returns `false` for pretty much all properties as the type of property is `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.EntityProperty`, so everything falls into the parser. `TryParseJson` then converts strings that look like Octal numbers into the decimal representation of the Octal.

Comment: @Zhaph-BenDuguid you’re right, thanks for the fix! I’m actually using this in production and made the same fix a long time ago, but forgot to update the code here, my bad.

I’ve also added conditionals to skip de-/serialization of properties with the [IgnoreProperty] attribute.

Comment: Yep, it would appear we've done something similar with: `!Attribute.IsDefined(property, typeof(JsonIgnoreAttribute))`