# Stop Azure Tables treating strings as octal values

Tags: c#, azure-table-storage

We have defined an Azure Table object with a string property that we are storing a random 6 digit code in:

```
SampleTable : TableEntity {

  public SampleTable (string partitionKey, string rowKey, string randomCode){
    PartitionKey = partitionKey;
    RowKey = rowKey;
    RandomCode = randomCode;
  }

  public string RandomCode {get; set;}
}
```

Looking at the table structure that is created in Azure Tables, the RandomCode is stored as a string.

If we create a model with the randomcode set to `034120` Storage Explorer shows the stored value correctly as `034120`, however when we retrieve the value back using:

```
TableOperation retrieveOperation = TableOperation
                                     .Retrieve<SampleTable>(partitionKey, rowKey);

// Execute the retrieve operation.
TableResult retrievedResult = Table.Execute(retrieveOperation);

var result = retrievedResult.Result as SampleTable;
```

The value of RandomCode is `102510` (the Octal representation of 34,120).

Is there any way to force Azure Tables to treat our string properties as strings regardless of the contents? At the moment we're looking to force our random codes to start with 1-9, but this seems rather redundant.

As an interesting point, testing other options shows that storing a value starting `0x` assumes the value is a hexadecimal and returns the decimal version of the value, as a string. I might possibly understand this if the model treated the value as an int, but we're treating everything as strings.

Comment: I don't think there is anything to do with Azure Table here. Could you please share more details on how you create the entity, how you retrieve the entity? If you do creation and retrieval both by Azure Storage Client Library, I don't believe the issue could happen.

Comment: Neither Azure Table Storage nor the client SDK changes the values of string properties in your class. All of the issues you see above are 100% due to the issues in your own code unfortunately since you have not posted enough details (see comment from Zhaoxing) it is impossible to help you out what you are doing wrong.

Comment: Browsing through our repo, it looks like we also have a custom reader/writer based on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34557105/ which is handling custom types and is probably the cause. I'll confirm once I'm in the office.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there's additional code within our codebase causing the problem, the underlying behaviour is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, Azure table storage service and Azure Storage Client Library do not actively convert a string value to octal value. According to your description and code, I create a sample to reproduce the issue, the code works fine on my side. You could refer to the sample code to check what’s the difference with your code.

**Create SampleTable class**

```
public class SampleTable : TableEntity
{

    public SampleTable(string partitionKey, string rowKey, string randomCode)
    {
        PartitionKey = partitionKey;
        RowKey = rowKey;
        RandomCode = randomCode;
    }

    public SampleTable() { }

    public string RandomCode { get; set; }
}
```

**Create table and insert an entity**

```
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(
    CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));

CloudTableClient tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();


CloudTable table = tableClient.GetTableReference("SampleTable");
table.CreateIfNotExists();

SampleTable st = new SampleTable("p001", "pr1", "034120");

TableOperation insertOperation = TableOperation.Insert(st);

table.Execute(insertOperation);
```

Check entity in storage explorer 
[image]

**Retrieve a single entity**

```
string partitionKey = "p001";
string rowKey = "pr1";
TableOperation retrieveOperation = TableOperation.Retrieve<SampleTable>(partitionKey, rowKey);


TableResult retrievedResult = table.Execute(retrieveOperation);

var result = retrievedResult.Result as SampleTable;

string txt = string.Format("RandomCode: {0}", result.RandomCode.ToString());
```

[image]

> If we create a model with the randomcode set to 034120

Please share us the code you are using to create the model.

Comment: Thanks Fred, I'll take another look and share what I can (we do have another class sitting between the concrete class and EntityTable, so it's possible we're doing something in there). As I note if I change the value in the table via storage explorer to `0x34120` this is also converted from hexadecimal.

Comment: Browsing through our repo, it looks like we also have a custom reader/writer based on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34557105/ which is handling custom types and is probably the cause.